# R-Adding lines to plotly animation

Tags: r, plotly

I am unable to add lines to my animation. I need the points to be connected, so in the end the outcome will look like a linear function with some points along the way.

```
animacja <- dane_wybrane |> 
  plot_ly(
    x = ~Walka,
    type = "scatter",
    mode = "lines",
    marker = list(
      size = 5,
      color = ifelse(dane_wybrane$Czy_zwyciezca == "True","green","red")
    ),
    line = list(shape = "linear"),
    frame = ~Walka
  ) |> 
  add_lines(
    x = ~Walka,
    y = ~`Liczba punktow`,
    line = list(color = "blue", width = 2),
    frame = ~Walka
  )|> 
  # add_trace(
  #   x = ~Walka,
  #   y = ~Kopniecia,
  #   name = "Kopniecia",
  #   type = "scatter",
  #   mode = "line",
  #   line = list(color = "yellow")
  # ) |> 
  animation_opts(
    frame = 200,
    redraw = FALSE,
    easing = "linear",
    transition = 0
  )
animacja
```

I have tried both add_lines(), add_trace() and add_paths() and neither have worked

Comment: Your question isn't reproducible, and without your data, there are a lot of different ways I can perceive your expected outcome. Instead of guessing (me-- my guessing), can you make your question reproducible? t looks like you're new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from `dput()` or `reprex::reprex()`. Check it out: [making R reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269).